# Error: sock.c:216 UCX ERROR send(fd=-1) failed: Bad file descriptorin - Fortran/C++ parallel code in RHEL system

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, fortran

I'm trying to run a parallel code that is written in Fortran and C++. I have ran many versions of this code but I'm getting an error which I haven't seen beforer `sock.c:216  UCX  ERROR send(fd=-1) failed: Bad file descriptor`. I tried to isolate the error and I found that the code fails before a MPI_BARRIER call. Below is what I get in my error file:

```
    ==== backtrace (tid: 107307) ====
 0 0x000000000003afe7 __GI_____strtoll_l_internal()  :0
 1 0x0000000000037900 atoi()  ???:0
 2 0x00000000006b7474 (anonymous namespace)::readHeader()  *some address*/phastaIO/phastaIO.cc:149
 3 0x00000000006b79f2 readheader_()  *some address*/phastaIO/phastaIO.cc:281
 4 0x00000000004cdf4c readnblk_()  *some address*/readnblk.f:110
 5 0x000000000046a6be input_()  *some address*/phSolver/common/input.f:34
 6 0x000000000044bbd6 phasta()  *some address*/phSolver/common/phasta.cc:153
 7 0x000000000044b977 main()  *some address*/phSolver/incompressible/main.c:7
 8 0x0000000000022555 __libc_start_main()  ???:0
 9 0x000000000044b8a9 _start()  ???:0
=================================
 *** Process received signal ***
 Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
 Signal code:  (-6)
 Failing at address: 0x14e30001a32b
```

The readnblk.f's line 110 is as follows: `call readheader(igeom,fname1,nshg,ione,'integer', iotype)`

The phastaIO.cc's lines are as follows:

```
void readheader( int* fileDescriptor,
             const char keyphrase[],
             void* valueArray,
             int*  nItems,
             const char  datatype[],
             const char  iotype[] ) {
    
    int filePtr = *fileDescriptor - 1;
    FILE* fileObject;
    int* valueListInt;

    LastHeaderKey[ filePtr ] = const_cast< char* >( keyphrase ); 
    LastHeaderNotFound = false;

    fileObject = fileArray[ filePtr ] ;
    Wrong_Endian = byte_order[ filePtr ];

    isBinary( iotype );
    typeSize( datatype );   //redundant call, just avoid a compiler warning..

    valueListInt = static_cast< int* >( valueArray );
    int ierr = readHeader( fileObject ,
                           keyphrase,
                           valueListInt,
Line 281                   *nItems ) ;

    byte_order[ filePtr ] = Wrong_Endian ;

    if ( ierr ) LastHeaderNotFound = true;
    
    return ;
}
```